# Show that $e^{z+z^3/3}$ is Hayman admissable

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-combinatorics

> Show that $f(z) := e^{z+\frac{z^3}{3}}$ is Hayman admissable.
>
> Remark: You can find the relevant definition from p.565 of the Floyd & Sedgewick book below.

From the lecture I know the following theorem:

> Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. If the Taylor coefficients of $e^{P(z)}$ are positive for large ennough $n$, then $e^{P(z)}$ is Hayman admissable.

I would say that this already solves the exercise, since

$$\exp(z) := \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

is always positive and thus also $e^{z+\frac{z^3}{3}}$. Is it really that easy or am I missing something here?[image]

Comment: I concur, it really is that easy.

Comment: I concur.  But if you need some evidence:  $$1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{3 z^4}{8}+\frac{7 z^5}{40}+\frac{9
   z^6}{80}+\frac{39 z^7}{560}+\frac{137 z^8}{4480}+\frac{641 z^9}{40320}+\frac{3449
   z^{10}}{403200}+O\left(z^{11}\right)$$

Comment: Since $$
{\rm e}^{z + z^3 /3}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}}  \times \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{z^{3n} }}{{3^n n!}}} 
$$ and the product of two power series with non-negative coefficients is a power series with non-negative coefficients, the result follows. (Can you see that the coefficients in fact are never zero?)